# ImportError: cannot import name 'csr_array' from 'scipy.sparse'

Tags: python, scipy

I'm encountering an ImportError when trying to import csr_array from scipy.sparse in my Python code. The specific error message I'm getting is:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'csr_array' from 'scipy.sparse'`

I'm using SciPy version 1.7.0 and I followed the official documentation, but it seems that csr_array is not available in the scipy.sparse module.

`from scipy.sparse import csr_array`

Comment: `csr_array` is present in the newest versions (1.10).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to import csr_matrix instead.

To resolve the issue, modify your import statement from:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_array
```

to:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
```

If you are using an older version of SciPy, you can upgrade it using the following command:

```
!pip install --upgrade scipy
```

After making these changes, the csr_matrix attribute should be imported successfully without any errors.

Using csr_matrix should provide you with the desired functionality.

I hope this helps!

Comment: `csr_array` is a relatively recent addition, not a removal.